# Javascript - Edit Forms Issue

Tags: javascript, django

I have a form that will show profile information and I have a javascript that will edit the form. The edit was working ok, but don't know what I did now. I'm not a javascript expert, but I been pulling my hair trying to figure out the problem. 
Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Enable all the text fields, rename value of Edit button and submit the forms

    function activate(){
        get_button_name = $("#save_button").text();

        if (get_button_name == 'Edit'){
        $(".enable").attr('disabled', false);
        $("#save_button").text('Save');
        }

        else {
            $("#editProfileForm").submit();
        }

    }


    function search(){
        document.getElementById('button-name').value="search";
    }

</script>

<div id="profile_form">
    <form id="editProfileForm" method="get" action="/updateProfile/">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
    <h1 style="margin-left: 40px;">Profile</h1>

    <!-- Search box -->
    <div id="search">
        <input type="text" name="search_input" id="search_input" style="display: inline;" />
        <button type="submit" onclick="search()">Search</button>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="button-name" id="button-name" value="" />

    {% for i in profile %}
    <tr>
        <td><label>Firstname:</label></td>
        <td><input class="enable" name="firstname" type="text" disabled value="{{ i.firstname }}" /></td> 
    </tr>


    <tr>    
        <td><label>Lastname:</label></td> 
        <td><input class="enable" name="lastname" type="text" disabled value="{{ i.lastname }}" /></td> 
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><label>Email:</label></td> 
        <td><input class="enable" name="email" type="text" disabled value="{{ i.user.email}}" /></td> 
    </tr>   

    <tr>

        <td><label>Location:</label></td> 
        <td><input class="enable" type="text" name="location" disabled value="{{ i.location }}" /></td> 
    </tr>


    {% endfor %}
    </table>
    {% if edit %}
    <button style="margin: 30px 30px" id='save_button' type='button' onclick='activate()'>Edit</button>
    {% endif %}
    </form>

</div>
```

Here is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/U5jhc/

Comment: It would be helpful to give us more information about the details of what you want to happen, and what is going wrong. For small js problems like these, it's also helpful to paste your code into a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) so we can test it out ourselves.

Comment: the profile it show on the forms for example value="{{ i.location }}" that show the profile location. This using django. What I want to do is that when I hit the edit button, it will let me input in the form to then hit save and save the new information on the database. The problem is that when I hit edit, it does not do anything.

Comment: I never use jsfiddle.net. I see four windows, where do I put the code on?

Comment: Your code appears to work on my browser. What browser are you using? http://jsfiddle.net/XNTHz/

Comment: Sorry, there's no apparent problem with it, and it's working in Chrome for me.

Comment: When I run the javascript alone without the html on jsfiddle I get this as the output: }//]]> Is  this normal?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35853/discussion-between-cypress-frankenfeld-and-amb1s1)

Comment: Here is my page source when I run the actual project. http://jsfiddle.net/AEUnr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was on the django setting. I had the wrong setting for causing the jquery file not to load.